# data set ‘ebicat37’ not found

Tags: r, bioconductor, gwas

[Snapshot of  the Warning message upon reinstalling the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZqP3.jpg)

[Snapshot of my error in loading ebicat37 data from "gwascat" package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9tEr.jpg)

I am new to R and Bioconductor. Currently, taking an online edX course on Bioconductor. As instructed, after loading the "gwascat" package, when trying to load data(ebicat37), I am getting the following message:

`library(gwascat)`

> gwascat loaded.  Use makeCurrentGwascat() to extract current image.
> from EBI.  The data folder of this package has some legacy extracts.

`data(ebicat37)`

> Warning message:
>
> In data(ebicat37) : data set ‘ebicat37’ not found.

What is the problem and how to rectify the error since I need to load the data(ebicat37) to work with  GWAS catalog stored in GRCh37.

I have attached my session info together with this question:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Error in loading the data(ebicat37) after reinstalling the package in the new session too. Following is my error details:

```
> remove.packages("gwascat")
```

```
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. 
The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+   install.packages("BiocManager") 
> BiocManager::install("gwascat")
getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories,
see '?repositories' for details
replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/
Bioconductor version 3.13 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 4.1.0
 (2021-05-18)
Installing package(s) 'gwascat'
trying URL https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/gwasca>t_2.24.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 35563316 bytes (33.9 MB)
downloaded 33.9 MB
package ‘gwascat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcFJOTu\downloaded_packages
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
 path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library
 packages:
 Matrix, mgcv
> library(gwascat)
gwascat loaded.  Use makeCurrentGwascat() to extract current image.
from EBI.  The data folder of this package has some legacy extracts.
> data(ebicat37)
Warning message:
In data(ebicat37) : data set ‘ebicat37’ not found
```

Comment: I downloaded the packages as per course guidelines. The following installation code was provided within the course to run and download the necessary packages. 
 `BiocManager::install(c("genefu", "COPDSexualDimorphism", "gwascat", "hgu133a.db", "genomicsclass/tissuesGeneExpression"))`

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow Thanks for your reply. I tried downloading the package as mentioned in Bioconductor website link which u have posted. Yet, I get the same error when I try to load the `data(ebicat37)`

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow I  removed the package and while installing it again I get this warning message. Screenshot Image attached above.

Comment: @SHAS thanks for posting the error messages - but could you paste them directly into the question and then format them using the quote formatting button. Images tend to dissappear after a while and aren't very helpful for people trying to google search the error term. Thanks.

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow Thank you, Still, the error continues and I have included the error in the question too.

Comment: @user438383 Ok, noted. Thank you!!!

Comment: Go to `library` folder and manually delete the package and install again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by:

1. using an older version of `R`, specifically `3.6.3`; and
2. removing `BiocManager` and reinstalling an older version (`1.30.16`).

Note: you will be prompted to update `BiocManager`, but don't do it.  Using this older version of `BiocManager`, you can then install and use ebicat37.